# Excel VBA verify if all fields in a column in a table are filled before saving

Tags: vba, excel

I am having troubles with a VBA code I want to write. I have looked through different questions here and in other forums but I cant find something that will help my needs.

My problem is about a table named "TableLaw", with about 43 columns and over 10000 rows.

Practically, my need can be divided in two parts:

- Verify all fields in column [Comments] from TableLaw. Meaning, I want to see if all data fields in that column are not empty. So I will need to check over 10000 rows. **Please note: the fields I am verifying have a formula in them, so they are not really empty. The formula concatenates some cells to form a comment. I need to see if there is a comment or not in each  cell**
- If there are empty fields in the column [Comments], I want to block the workbook from saving. I would like to also highlight the cells that are 'empty' in the column to help the user see which field in the column he needs to work on.

I have no problems with the blocking from saving part, but I am having serious trouble with even forming a For Each or something that will iterate from cell to cell in the column [Comment] checking if the cell is empty or it has a formula only and highlight those cells which are empty.

It is important to use structure names like [Comments] because the user might add new columns to the table.

Thanks, and sorry for the trouble. I am relatively new to VBA and my prior knowledge in programming is few.

I have seen lots of complicated code snippets that I just can not understand, but I got this and I am sure all of you will laugh at my incompetence and doubt if I really did something:

```
Sub TableTest()

Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim tRows As Long
Dim tCols As Long

Dim lo As ListObject
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lr As ListRow
Dim lc As ListColumn

'I used this to get the column number and then use it in a For cycle to go through all cells in the column
col = WorksheetFunction.Match("COMMENTS", Sheets("Orders").Range("5:5"), 0)

Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TableLaw")
With tbl.DataBodyRange
    tRows = .Rows.Count
    tCols = .Columns.Count
End With

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Orders")
Set lo = ws.ListObjects("TableLaw")

For Each lr In lo.ListRows
    Cells(lr, col).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
Next lr



End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
'I added the range like this because I do not know how to add the column name.
   If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Orders").Range("AM6:AM10500")) <> "" Then
      MsgBox "Workbook will not be saved unless all comments are added"
      Cancel = True
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You may be over-engineering the problem, can a `COUNTIF` be used?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav count if works great, you are right about that. But how can I use the column name to go through each of its field and verify if they are empty or not and colour them if they are?

Comment: maybe like so `=COUNTIF(Table1[[#All],[Test_Field3]],"<>""""")` using `worksheetfunction`

Answer (score 0):

You can check it with the .Value function

ie.

```
If (Range("A1").Value = "") Then
  ''' PROCESS CODE
End If
```

Comment: Thanks but I would like to use the column name as a range instead of A1

Comment: That's fine you can use that too, just cycle through starting at the last row... The above is just an arbitrary example